# How to use multiple conditional operators using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use combination of the 2 operators:  the &&  and the || operator using C#.  I have 5 variables that I would like to make sure if these conditions are met.
varRequestedDate
varTotdayDate
varExpectedDate
Approval1
Approval2
Here is what I have for my current condition but would like to add other variables adding the OR operator:

```
if (varRequestedDate != ("&nbsp;") && varExpectedDate < varTotdayDate)
```

here is the pseudocode for what I would like to see after the updated version:

```
(if varRequestedDate is not blank 
and varExpectedDate is less than varTotdayDate
and either Approved1 OR Approved2 = Yes)
send email()
```

i cannot figure out how to do this.
thanks

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/c-operators-and-precedence.html take a look at this too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to add nested parentheses:

```
if (varRequestedDate != "&nbsp;" 
    && varExpectedDate < varTotdayDate
    && (Approved1 == "Yes" || Approved2 == "Yes")
)
    sendEmail();
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of readability and expressiveness I would extract the boolean values into meaningfully named variables:

```
var isDateRequested = varRequestedDate != ("&nbsp;");
var isDateWithinRange = varExpectedDate < varTotdayDate;
var isApproved = Approved1 == "Yes" || Approved2 == "Yes";

if (isDateRequested && isDateWithinRange && isApproved)
{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest logical operators using parentheses (just like arithmetic operators). Otherwise they follow a defined precedence going left to right.

```
if (
    varRequestedDate !=("&nbsp;") && 
    varExpectedDate < varTodayDate && 
    (Approved1==Yes||Approved2==yes))
```